# Cruzar dois dataframes

Tags: r, dataframe

Considerando 2 dataframes de tamanhos diferentes: o df1 constituído por 2 conjuntos de pares de dados (origem, destino) com a mesma origem (um conjunto agrega vertices com origem em A e outro agrega vertices com origem em E) e, o df2 constituido por pares de vertices (x,y):

```
df1 = data.frame(
    origem = c("A","A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "E", "E", "E", "E"), 
    destino=c("A","B","C","F", "J", "H", "G", "E", "D", "G", "F"))
df2 = data.frame(
    x = c("A","A", "E", "J", "C", "C"), 
    y = c("A","C","G","B", "F", "H"))
```

Para cada **conjunto definido em df1 com a mesma origem** (p.e. GA para os vértices destino com origem em A) pretendo identificar todos os vértices destino que formam pares (x,y) de vértices pertencentes a esse mesmo grupo.
Por exemplo, o grupo com origem em A (GA) apresenta o seguinte conjunto de vértices destino {A, B, C, F, J, H,G } e os vértices que formam pares (x, y) constituídos apenas por vértices desse grupo são:  A, B, C, F, H ( J não existe na coluna y de df2, G existe na coluna y mas está associado a x=E e E não é vértice do conjunto GA). O objetivo seria obter uma tabela com a seguinte informação onde 1 marca os vértices destino nas condições acima:

```
   origem destino flag
1       A       A    1
2       A       B    1
3       A       C    1
4       A       F    1
5       A       J    0
6       A       H    1
7       A       G    0
8       E       E    0
9       E       D    0
10      E       G    1
11      E       F    0
```

Alguém consegue ajudar? Obg

Answer (score -2):

```
require( purrr )

grupo <- unique( df1$origem )

seq( grupo ) %>%
  map( ~df1[ df1$origem == grupo[ .x ], 'destino'] ) ->
    destinos_na_grupo

faz <- function( grp, dest ){
  resposta    <- FALSE
  ese_destino <- destinos_na_grupo[[ grp ]][ dest ]
  ori         <- grupo[ grp ]
  z           <- df2[ df2$y == ese_destino, 'x']
  if( length( z ) > 0 ){
    resposta <- z %in% c( ori, destinos_na_grupo[[ grp ]] )
  }
  resposta
}

seq( grupo ) %>%
  map( function( grp ){
    seq( destinos_na_grupo[[ grp ]] ) %>%
    map_int( ~faz( grp, .x ) )
  }
) %>% unlist -> flag

df1$flag <- flag

df1
#   origem destino flag
#1       A       A    1
#2       A       B    1
#3       A       C    1
#4       A       F    1
#5       A       J    0
#6       A       H    1
#7       A       G    0
#8       E       E    0
#9       E       D    0
#10      E       G    1
#11      E       F    0
```